# Scheduling in Spring: @Schedule and @EnableScheduling lead to multiple calls of method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-scheduled

I have a service which has to run a job to get and refresh it's data from another service. The job has to be run on startup and every couple of hours/days. I was looking into the behavior of the scheduled job and it seems to be called two times consecutively according to the logs (see below).

```
@Service
public class ServiceImpl implements ServiceInterface {

@Autowired
private FetchService fetchService;

private int timesCalled = 0;
private Data data;

@PostConstruct
private void initialize() {
    data = fetchService.getAndUpdate();
}

@Scheduled(cron = "* */5 * * * *")
private void refresh() {
    LOG.info(appContext.getId());
    LOG.info("This object: " + System.identityHashCode(this));
    LOG.info("Times called: " +  timesCalled);
    timesCalled++;
    data = fetchService.getAndUpdate();
}
...
```

Here also the logs where the refresh method is being called every 5 minutes, as can be seen it is being called two times:

```
2020-07-02 17:30:00.006  INFO 30416 --- [   scheduling-1] c.d.p.d.service.ServiceImpl  : org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@6db9cae5
2020-07-02 17:30:00.006  INFO 30416 --- [   scheduling-1] c.d.p.d.serice.ServiceImpl  : This object: 357813323
2020-07-02 17:30:00.006  INFO 30416 --- [   scheduling-1] c.d.p.d.service.ServiceImpl  : Times called: 1
....
2020-07-02 17:30:32.001  INFO 30416 --- [   scheduling-1] c.d.p.d.service.ServiceImpl  : org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@6db9cae5
2020-07-02 17:30:32.001  INFO 30416 --- [   scheduling-1] c.d.p.d.service.ServiceImpl  : This object: 357813323
2020-07-02 17:30:32.001  INFO 30416 --- [   scheduling-1] c.d.p.d.service.ServiceImpl  : Times called: 2
```

I don't have a web.xml and am using only defaults. I have used the @EnableScheduling tag at root level:

```
@EnableScheduling
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

I looked into similar questions but couldn't find anything which could help me to find the source of this bug. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: What's the value of `refresh.schedule`? Maybe you want to take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: It's a normal cron job format: * */5 * * * *

Comment: I'm flagging this question as off topic, because the behaviour is caused by a simple typo in your cron expression and therefore of no interest for future readers. Change your cron value according to [spring docs - scheduling tasks](https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Behaviour you describe is normal and intended.

As you wrote, your cron expression is `* */5 * * * *`, which means, according to [the Spring guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/), that it will run every second of every 5th minute:

> A cron-like expression, extending the usual UN*X definition to include triggers on the second, minute, hour, day of month, month, and day of week.
>
> For example, {@code "0 * * * * MON-FRI"} means once per minute on weekdays (at the top of the minute - the 0th second).
> The fields read from left to right are interpreted as follows.
>
> - second
> - minute
> - hour
> - day of month
> - month
> - day of week

That can be easily reproduced by taking your code and the cron expression:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "* */5 * * * *")
private void refresh() {
    log.info("Times called: " +  timesCalled);
    timesCalled++;
}
```

And observe its behaviour:

```
14:20:13.001  INFO 8980 --- [   sch-1] com.example.demo.Sched   : Times called: 13
14:20:14.001  INFO 8980 --- [   sch-1] com.example.demo.Sched   : Times called: 14
14:20:15.003  INFO 8980 --- [   sch-1] com.example.demo.Sched   : Times called: 15
14:20:59.002  INFO 8980 --- [   sch-1] com.example.demo.Sched   : Times called: 59
14:25:00.000  INFO 8980 --- [   sch-1] com.example.demo.Sched   : Times called: 60
14:25:01.000  INFO 8980 --- [   sch-1] com.example.demo.Sched   : Times called: 61
14:25:02.001  INFO 8980 --- [   sch-1] com.example.demo.Sched   : Times called: 62
14:25:03.002  INFO 8980 --- [   sch-1] com.example.demo.Sched   : Times called: 63
```

As you see it runs every second, until the minute ends. Than waits till 14:25 and runs again for every second.

#### But why does it only run 2 times at the questions case?

That's easy: `data = fetchService.getAndUpdate();` takes about 30 seconds, and because you have only a single Thread for your scheduling, it must wait for the last iteration to finish, until it can start over again.

---

### Solution

To fix that, simply replace the first wildcard with a `0`:

```
0 */5 * * * *
```

And your job will run every 5 minutes.